# How to determine which traffic goes over the PPTP VPN?

Tags: macos, network, security, vpn

I setup a PPTP VPN on mac os x lion, on the advanced tab I do not have the send all traffic over VPN connection checked. I only want traffic to a specific server connected to go through the vpn, everything else should not be sent over the vpn.

Where do I look to find out which IP addresses will be included for traffic over the vpn and which ones will not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the route command to declare a static route?

For instance, I use the following with my VPN:

```
sudo route -v -net 10.41.0.0 -netmask 255.255.0.0 -interface ppp0
```

This tells any traffic going to 10.41.x.x to go over the VPN interface (ppp0).

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `add` to your command for it to work on OS X.

First, connect your vpn and find the interface name: `ifconfig`. Mine was also ppp0. Then run: `sudo route -v add -net 10.41.0.0 -netmask 255.255.0.0 -interface ppp0`.

`-net` is a modifier on the `add` command. 
Works like a charm.